# JavaScript Use classList attribute to call internal variable

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a basic typing game to help teach myself Thai typing and I'm breaking down the keyboard into sections (14 total).

I'm using an onclick from HTML to call a function in my js file and that works great.  I pass 'thaiRightTop' from the initial onclick and the text loads fine.

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="selector(thaiRightTop, className='thaiRightTop')">Thai Right Top</a>
```

JS

```
const thaiRightTop = ['ภ','ถ']

function selector(ele, className){
        let textDisplay = document.querySelector('#textDisplay')
        textDisplay.innerHTML = ''
        textDisplay.classList = ''
        textDisplay.classList = className
        const words = createWords(ele, 3,5, 60)
        addSpan(words)
    }
```

However once the user has typed out the full string of words correctly I want to load another set of words using the same array.

Where I'm confused and having issues is calling the same selector function from with JS and using the classList class name to call through the variable ele

```
if (correct === true){
    let textDisplay = document.querySelector('#textDisplay')
    className = textDisplay.classList
    selector(ele=className, className=String(className))
}
```

I know I can define if/else if/switch case statement and hard code each array name (total of 14) but that seems like it's really redundant and unnecessary.  Is there an easy way to use a class name to refer to a const?

Thanks in advance and apologies if this is a repeat question but I couldn't find anything anywhere else...

Added a CodePen Link - Once the first sentence is completed I want to reload the the same set (thaiRightTop) which will create another random sequence of words.

I created an IneffecientSelector to show what I didn't want to do but how it should work (sorry if I used codePen instead of SO Snippet, I'm more familiar with CP).

[codePen Link](https://codepen.io/linusidom/pen/vYNowPb)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Can you make a runnable StackOverflow snippet? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake!
textDisplay.classList returns a DOMTokenList.  I wasn't parsing that as a list, I was passing the whole thing thinking it was a value already.  I also changed my keyboard sections to a dictionary which made it easier to work with.

Thanks!